# How do you add page jumps in Android similar to HTML?

Tags: android, page-jump

I have been looking for a simple way to jump via link to a certain part of the screen, similar to the a href /#linkname in HTML. But I would like to do this programatically and not a webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your layout in a `ScrollView` and use `scrollTo`